# How to make dynamic form in html based on previous input in realtime using vannilajs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, input

I have a form like this and it will generate the amount of form based on the total value that inputted in this form

```
<form>
    <input type="Number" name="delivery">
</form>
```

for example, if the user filled the input 3 it will generate 3 new forms automatically in real-time

```
<form>
    <input type="Number" name="delivery">
    <input type="text" name="destination">
    <input type="text" name="destination">
    <input type="text" name="destination">
</form>
```

My application doesn't use jquery so I have to do this in vanilla js.
please guide me to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might do it:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('delivery');
const form = document.getElementById('form');

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    form.innerHTML = '';

    for (i = 0; i < parseInt(input.value); i++) {
        let formInput = document.createElement('input');
        formInput.setAttribute('type', 'text')
        formInput.setAttribute('name', 'destination');
        form.appendChild(formInput);
    }
})
```

```html
<input type="Number" id="delivery">



<form id="form">

</form>
```

When ever the number changes the inputs will be added accordingly.

Comment: how to make if the number change to 0 and it will delete input that created and if the number change it will generate based on current number

Comment: oh, I see .. its because I make a little modification . and all good now.. and I change event for add event listener to ('input') instead of ('change') for the input of the more realtime show.. :)  .. actually I have tried using for loops but I forgot to parse the input number to int and it makes messed output. thank you, bro.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
let inputElem = document.createElement('input');
```

To create new input elements
and

```
document.querySelector('form').appentChild(inputElem);
```

Append this new input elemnt to the parent form

You can use a for loop to create as much element you want

Like this

```
<form> 
<input type="Number" name="delivery" onchange="createInput(this)"> 
<div id='dynamic'>
</div>
</form>

<script>

function createInput(elem){
     const container = document.getElementById('dynamic');
     container.innerHTML = '';
     const count = elem.value;
     for(let i= 0; i< count;i++){
        const newInput = document.createElement('input'); container.appendChild(newInput);
     }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I want to make it automatically rendered real-time base on the value in the type number input

Comment: Yes you can do it

Comment: :( I don't know how to do it/.. for example like addeventlistener('click') is there event for addeventlistener('filled') and it will make an action

Comment: Or you can use onkeyup event